# Powerbi rest api AddRows

Tags: powerbi

I am working on a realtime dashboard, i'd like to use the powerbi Rest Api.

My question how does the updating of rows work. I have 1300 records to load once and then update 2 columns for each row every 20 seconds.

The only rest call I see is to addrows, but it's not clear how it handles update of rows if it does

Answer (score 3):

You have two patterns you can choose from:

You can send data in batches: upload 1300 rows, then call DELETE on the rows, then call upload with the next payload of rows.

Here's the DELETE method you need to all. We're adopting REST standards for our APIs so the 'methods' are the REST verbs :).  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238041.aspx

Alternately you can incrementally update the data:  You'd add a 'timestamp' column to your data set.  Then in your query (like in Q&A) you'd ask for "show data for the last 20 seconds".  If you do this, set the FIFO retention policy when you create the data set so you don't run out of space.

In either case, double check the number of rows you're pushing fit within the limits we spell out. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn950053.aspx

HTH, 
-Lukasz

Comment: thanks lukasz. you saved my life from my manager. thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

i was searching something in powerbi docs that could help me in creating a report with rest APIs. couldn't find it exact though. however made a work-around.

1. firsly, I created a push dataset schema in powerbi with help of post push dataset rest api.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/push-datasets/datasets-post-dataset-in-group
2. then I pushed rows/record/data into my dataset with this post rows in push dataset.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/push-datasets/datasets-post-rows-in-group
3. then I went to powerbi service, and created a visual report manually there.
4. after this I embedded that report in my react app.
5. finally my report was live.
6. now if wanted to update my report in real time, I called delete push dataset rows api to delete the existing rows/records from my dataset.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/push-datasets/datasets-delete-rows-in-group

7. and then called the post push dataset rows api again with new updated data. (repeated step 2)
8. and then finally I refreshed my website page, and now I see the updated visual report in my website.

it took me too much time. so I can feel if you are struggling w/ powerbi rest api. it's not straightforward. so feel free to ask anything down below. will happy to help.